# What happens when a Dwolla guest checkout finally clears or fails to clear?

Tags: webhooks, checkout, dwolla

When a guest checkout completes successfully, the redirect and webhook postback are both passed parameters indicating a successful checkout. However, what happens if the ACH fails to clear several days later, or is cancelled by the receiver? Is the only way I can determine this by querying the transaction on the expected clearing date, or is there a webhook I am missing?

If this is accomplished by querying the transaction ID, and I check after the expected clearing date, is it *guaranteed* to not then clear after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dwolla has a Webhook called "[TransactionStatus](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/pages/webhooks/transactionstatus)". That Webhook will POST to your server whenever a transaction's status changes. On a typical transaction, you will get 2 notifications: first, that the transaction entered "pending" mode, and then finally when it enters "processed" (or "failed", "canceled") mode.

[Here's a page](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/pages/statuses) explaining the different statuses a transaction can be in.

Finally, if you decide to opt out for the manual polling method, you should know that as long as a transaction is in "pending" mode, that are no guarantees either way. That said, its very very rare for a transaction to stay pending after its clearing date.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I should have picked up on this from the docs, since it specifically mentions **any** state change.

Comment: -@Michael if the transaction ultimately fails to clear, does the sender's account get reimbursed?

Comment: @Tim if the transaction fails to clear, the sender's account would have never been debited and hence would not need a corresponding credit for "reimbursement". Think if it in the same way if you wrote  a bad check that bounces, you never really had the money to begin with so you wouldn't be reimbursed.

Comment: @Russ, so this appears notably different from the regular `transaction/send()` API call in which the money will be transferred from the sender's to the recipient's Dwolla account regardless of the status of the recipient's account.